# 1996 Toyota Tacoma Random Misfire

Tags: toyota, misfire, tacoma

I have a 96 2.4l tacoma that has right under 200,000 miles on it. Most of the time it runs great but randomly it starts misfiring. Only when it's up to operating temp but besides that there's no rhyme or reason to it. When it starts missing the a/c doesn't blow cold and my code reader won't connect with the ecu. It's been doing it a lot here lately. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Once it does start running correctly again, can you read the ECU at that point? If so, any codes?

Comment: Have you checked if the ht leads are deteriorated?

Comment: Yes I can read the codes when it's running fine but the only codes are for the catalytic converter cause it was removed and straight pipes by the previous owner. And what is the HT leads?? And I will go re read them as soon as it start running right again.

Comment: The HT leads are the spark plug cables

Comment: Oh ok thanks.  I just replaced the spark plug wires about three months ago or so. I've got a new rotor button to out on and maybe that will help.